# delete process started by mistake and stopped. What happened to the files?

Tags: nautilus, files, delete, permanent-delete

I have accidentally started a delete process for a huge folder on a remote machine (a cluster running linux) on which I navigate the folders/access the files via Nautilus through the command "Connect to server". On this machine I do not have a trash. I have stopped the delete process after 1 or 2 seconds (red button in the window with the progress bar) and apparently all the filed are still there. How can I check that no files have been damaged/partially removed?

Answer (score 1):

Delete doesn't corrupt file content. It just removes the meta info so this is a all or none process. If you know the count of files check if anything is missing.

There is a chance (since target was a huge folder) that nothing is lost because the process needs a recursive search and identifying which files should be removed and with a huge folder that process takes some time.